# Curved CSS nav dropdown like OS-X dock downloads

Tags: css

I am relatively new to CSS but wanted to have a nav dropdown that behaves like to downloads on the OSX dock, meaning the items are not in a straight line, but fall out in a curved formation (and from header and down), with same style of animation.

If somebody has a suggestion on how to proceed creating that (main steps), or perhaps such a nav dropdown already exists that I could use?

A simple straight dropdown seems soo traditional...

**EDIT:**
Here is a screendump of the osx dock download list:

[image]

But I want it to be "falling down" from a header nav, so it would perhaps look more like this (without the icons for each dropdown list item (here files), and perhaps a little bit more like a waterfall)...

[image]

Comment: could you post an image of the desired effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not (easily) possible with CSS. You should probably use javascript.

Here's an example: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/jquery-os-x-style-dock-and-stack-navigation--net-5535

[Demo (bottom-right).](http://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/358_jquery/example%20files/example3.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Louy! I added some screendumps to better describe what I am after (I do not want the dock effect itself, but the download files list effect).

Comment: Oh, sorry, missed that one! Indeed something like what I wanted, will check this out....